# how to add an existing schema to mysql on Windows

Tags: mysql

I have seen nothing on this topic anyplace, not even on here.

The problem is I have a MySQL 8.0 database that was on a previous hard disk (HD).  The boot on the original drive failed so I copied the folder

```
C:\ProgramData\mysql\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\my_db
```

over to the new HD, and have reinstalled MySQL.

My problem is I cannot see a way to mount this schema. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see your data because the info about existing objects is stored in system database which was not copied.

If your previous HDD is not available then:

1. Ensure that MySQL versions on old and new OS instances is completely the same. If not then remove MySQL on new OS and reinstall needed version.
2. Stop MySQL service.
3. Rename data folder (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 => C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0.bak).
4. Copy data folder from old HDD to new one completely.
5. Start MySQL service.
6. Backup needed old databases.
7. Stop MySQL service, remove data folder copied from old HDD and rename saved data folder back.
8. Start MySQL service.
9. Restore databases.
10. If you have reinstalled MySQL on the step 1 then upgrade MySQL version up to needed one by the common way.

Comment: 1. old and new are both 80 But on old drive it was named 8.0 and new - as you show.  4. under the myql Server 8.0 folder there is nothing but a single folder Data and in it I have put the scheme folder.    5.  service won't start